# Solving $2^a - 2^b = 2^x$ for extremely large $a$ and $b$

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the equation
$$2^a - 2^b = 2^x,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are *extremely* large numbers, for example $a =10^{10000 G}$, $B=10^{100G}$ with $G=10^{10^{100}}$, and I don't want to calculate the value of 2 to the power of $a$ or $b$ while solving the equation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you please give a real example of your $A$ and $B$ so that we see what you interpret as _big numbers_?

Comment: Could divide both sides by `2^a`, take logs and solve symbolically. `In[126]:= SolveValues[Log[1 - 2^(b - a)] == x - a, x]

Out[126]= {a + Log[1 - 2^(-a + b)]}` Still an awkward exponent but it should behave ok if approximate values are substituted for `a,b`.

Comment: I now realize that math.stackexchange.com was a better place for my question but I don't know how to move this question there?

Comment: @Domen, a real example : A or B=10^1000Googolplex

Comment: @Domen,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex

Comment: @Domen, Thank you for good editing my question.

Comment: @Domen,A is always greater than B,  a real example : A =10^10000Googolplex , B=10^100Googolplex

Comment: Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: *I don't want to calculate the value…* That’s good, because you wouldn’t be able to.

Comment: @Ghoster, I can calculate it very easily with Core i7000 on a Z790000 motherboard with a 64GGB Ram, I just have a small problem that my life is not long enough ):

Comment: *I can calculate it very easily* Do you understand how many digits $2^{10000\times10^{10^{100}}}$ has, and how much storage you would need for them? (I don’t think so!)

Comment: You can easily calculate powers of 2 until your 64 GB of RAM fills up, and that will *not* take your lifetime or anywhere near it. Try to figure out what exponent you will get to, and how it compares with $10000\times 10^{10^{100}}$.

Comment: Even if you used every atom in the observable universe to manufacture RAM, you couldn’t store your number.

Comment: *extremely large numbers* These are tiny compared with, say, $G^{G^{G….}}$ with the number of exponents in the tower being $G$. And that’s tiny compared with…

Comment: @Ghoster, WOW!, Now I understand my mistake, thank you very much for these interesting points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $a>b>0$:

$$
2^a-2^b=2^x\\
x=\frac{\ln(2^a-2^b)}{\ln2}
=\frac{\ln(2^b(2^{a-b}-1))}{\ln2}
=\frac{\ln(2^b)+\ln(2^{a-b}-1)}{\ln2}
=b+\frac{\ln(2^{a-b}-1)}{\ln2}\\
=b+\log_2(2^{a-b}-1)
$$
where $\log_2(z)=\ln z/\ln 2$ is the binary logarithm.
From here there are two cases: if you're able to compute $2^{a-b}$ then you're done,

```
With[{a = 1000, b = 993}, b + Log2[2^(a - b) - 1]]
(*    993 + Log[127]/Log[2]    *)
```

On the other hand, if $2^{a-b}$ is still too large to compute, you can do a series-expansion to get an approximate result: for $q\gg1$ we have
$$
\log_2(2^q-1)
=q-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k q}\cdot k\ln2}
=q-\frac{1}{2^q\cdot\ln2}
-\frac{1}{2^{2q}\cdot 2\ln2}+\cdots
$$
which converges very rapidly for large $q$. Setting $q=a-b$ we get
$$
x=b+\log_2(2^{a-b}-1)
=a-\frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\cdot 2^{k(a-b)}}
= a-\frac{1}{2^{a-b}\ln2}-\ldots
$$
(use more terms in the series expansion if this approximation is not accurate enough).

Let's try it out for $a=123$ and $b=45$:

```
With[{a = 123, b = 45},
  x1 = SolveValues[2^a - 2^b == 2^x, x, Reals][[1]];
  x2 = a - 1/(2^(a - b) Log[2]);
  x3 = a - 1/(2^(a - b) Log[2]) - 1/(2^(2 (a - b)) 2 Log[2]);]

N[x1, 75]
(*    122.999999999999999999999995226522529401007762572299599002776841803125665871    *)

N[x2, 75]
(*    122.999999999999999999999995226522529401007762572307496058813118106229976092    *)

N[x3, 75]
(*    122.999999999999999999999995226522529401007762572299599002776841803125665888    *)
```

Comment: It does not work for `{a = 10^6, b = 10^5 + 10^4}`.

Comment: @user64494 `With[{a = 10^6, b = 10^5 + 10^4}, x1 = Log[2^a - 2^b]/Log[2];
  x2 = a - 1/(2^(a - b) Log[2])];` evaluates fine!

Comment: @Roman Nice answer, but it doesn't avoid the calculation `2^(a-b)`. QP's expectation can't be fullfilled I think

Comment: @Roman, Thanks for your answer ,but as Ulrich said it doesn't avoid the calculation 2^(a-b), I asked this question here too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777274/solving-2a-2b-2x-for-extremely-large-a-and-b

Comment: I now realize that using 2^A or 2^B is problematic for the performance I need to run on the computer, but 2^(a-b) is fine, so let me try your answer with different numbers.

Comment: @Ulrich, and Roman, Thank you both, but this does not work for some numbers like what user64494 said, Ulrich solved them with " x2 = a - 1/(2^(a - b) Log[2])]" , How can I recognize those numbers?  (English is not my first language, hope you understand what I mean).

Comment: @maria if `2^(a-b)` is allowed, Romans answer is what you are looking for(see my comment concerning what user64494 said)

Comment: @Ulrich, 2^(a-b) is allowed, but some numbers works with "x=b+log2(2a−b−1)" and others works with "x = a - 1/(2^(a - b) Log[2])]" , now my computer need a condition to select one of these ways. what can that condition be?

Comment: @maria Please show these examples where the two formulas give different results

Comment: @Ulrich, Roman's example works with "x=b+log2(2a−b−1)", but user64494 example works with "x = a - 1/(2^(a - b) Log[2])]", now my computer need a condition to select one of these ways to calculate x.

Comment: @maria no that's not correct. user64494 's example is solved by Roman's formula **and** the exact solution!

Comment: @Ulrich,, let me try some numbers again, Thanks.

Comment: @Ulrich, for example even if you calculate this small numbers: a=5.257, b=5 with b+log2((2^a−b) −1) and x = a - 1/(2^(a - b) Log[2]) , you will get different result. the true answer is x=2.584, but non of them gets correct result.

Comment: @Roman, Thank you very much for the great answer, it works for many numbers, but I don't know why the result for some numbers is wrong, for example even if you try this small numbers: a=5.257, b=5 it gets wrong result.

Comment: so weird, with  a=6.257 , b=5 result is x=5.475 ,which is accurate, but with a=5.257, b=5 gets x=2.645 which is wrong.

Comment: @Maria, the $\approx$ symbol means "approximately equal to". If it's not accurate enough, just use more terms in the series expansion (I gave the full series but only used the first two terms).

Comment: @Maria I've added an example of using one more term in the series expansion.

Comment: Now I realize that my calculation was wrong and your answer is correct, you are a genius, thank you * G^G

Answer (score 0):

Take `Log` of your equation (or `Solve[2^x == 2^a - 2^b, x]`)

```
X=Log[2^A-2^B]/Log[2]

X/.{A->5.257,B->5}   (*2.64148*)
```

Comment: Note: A and B are very big numbers and I don't want to calculate the value of 2 to the power of A or B while solving the equation.

Comment: I need a method that can get C using only A and B, because the base always is 2.

Comment: You have a nonlinear equation in `a,b,x` , no chance to eliminate the base `2`. I only see a solution using `Log`

Comment: What is known about `a,b`? `a>b` && `a>>1`&& `b>>1`

Comment: a always is bigger than b

Comment: And perhaps `a-b>>1`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an amateur in math, and I don't know exactly what the >> operator means?

Comment: Something like " much greater"

Comment: Thanks, so a>b && a>>1&& b>>1 is correct

Comment: I realized x=(ln(a-b)^2)+Floor(b) works for some large/small numbers like this: 2^6.257-2^5=2^(ln(6.257-5)^2)+5)=2^5.476 , But does not work for many other numbers